# jQuery UI : When to use Widget Factory

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, widget

I'm a beginner in Javascript and web development in general. I'm building a web app that must be highly interactiv, so most of my work is about using Javascript to make this happen.
After having already written a good chunk of code, I feel like it won't be really maintainable and it's already hard to change, because I don't think I organised my code very well.

Essentially, I'm looking to separate the code that does actions on my objects, and the code that displays my objects. I've found that the Widget Factory might be a way to do that, but I can't really understand what it does exactly.

I red lots of documentation on it, but I don't know if it will be of any use for what I want to do. 
Can you tell me if it will be useful for me, and if not, what other tools or tutorials I should get my hands on to achieve this ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The widget factory is used to define custom jQuery widgets.

Your questions is very broad and generic to answer, since only you know what kind of objects/models and what kind of interactivity you are expecting to have between clients and the page.

In general you should create widgets when you are implementing a generic solution.
A widget is meant to be something re-usable that handles one particular think/job.

For example if you want a "rate this comment" thingy in your page were users can rate other user's comments, you would create a rate-comment widget and apply it to all your user-comment elements.